# No me muestra los resultados por pantalla, error undefined

Tags: javascript

tengo aquí un código que cuando el usuario pulsa el botón "pulsa aquí" almacena un libro y que el usuario debe escribir y cuando le de a mostrar cargue otra ventana y le muestre los libros almacenados, el problema es que al cargar la ventana cargan otra vez los botones de mostrar y pulsar aquí pero cuando le doy al mostrar de la ventana sale "undefined" como si no hubiera insertado nada previamente.

Aquí dejo mi código para que lo vean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var Libros= new Array(); 
var misLibros=new Array();

function PedirDatos(){
                

           
                var titulo=prompt("titulo del libro");
                var editorial=prompt("editorial del libro");
                
                var miLibro= new Libro(titulo,editorial);
                misLibros.push(miLibro);
                console.log(misLibros);
}
function insertarLibro(){

}
for(var x=0; x<4; x++){
    insertarLibro();
}
function misLibros(libro){
                this.libro=libro;
               
            }
           
function Libro(titulo, editorial){
                this.titulo=titulo;
                this.editorial=editorial;
                
               
            }





function Show(){
                   
    myWindows=window.open(" ", "Diseño Web", "width=300, height=200");
    myWindows.document.write(misLibros.forEach(element => {Libro.forEach(element => {(titulo[1]);});}));
                   
    
             }
</script>
<body>
        <input type="button" value="Mostrar" onclick="Show();">
        <input type="button" value="pulsa aqui" onclick="PedirDatos();">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo esta bien excepto la función `Show`, porque lo estas haciendo mal.

Lo que deberías de hacer es recorrer el array de `misLibros` y dentro del `callback` insertar el texto en la nueva ventana

```
function Show() {
    myWindows = window.open(" ", "Diseño Web", "width=300, height=200");
    misLibros.map(element => {
        myWindows.document.write(element.titulo);
    })
}
```

Tu código completo quedaría así.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var Libros = new Array();
var misLibros = new Array();

function PedirDatos() {

    var titulo = prompt("titulo del libro");
    var editorial = prompt("editorial del libro");

    var miLibro = new Libro(titulo, editorial);
    misLibros.push(miLibro);
    console.log(misLibros);
}

function insertarLibro() {

}
for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    insertarLibro();
}

function misLibros(libro) {
    this.libro = libro;

}

function Libro(titulo, editorial) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.editorial = editorial;


}


function Show() {

    myWindows = window.open(" ", "Diseño Web", "width=300, height=200");
    misLibros.map(element => {
        myWindows.document.write(element.titulo);
    })

}
</script>
<body>
        <input type="button" value="Mostrar" onclick="Show();">
        <input type="button" value="pulsa aqui" onclick="PedirDatos();">
</body>
</html>
```